# How to upload multiple images in multiple array of images using multipart in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data, swift4.1

I'm having a problem with uploading multiple images in multiple array of images using multipart in Alamofire.
Can any one help me? Thanks in advance!!

I am using the following code

```
let fileParameters = ["array_1": images1Array,
                      "array_2": images2Array]

func requestUpload(files: [String: Any]? = nil) {

Alamofire.upload( multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if let files = files {
            for (key, value) in files {
                if let images = value as? [UIImage] {
                    for (index, image) in images.enumerated() {
                        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
                        multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "\(index)", fileName: "\(index).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}, to: path , method: .post , headers: request.headers,
          encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

            self.validatedData(of: encodingResult, handler: { (result, error) in
                handler(result, error)
            })
        })
}
```

So i want to know how to append multiple images in particular key.

Server Request something like this :

```
"array1":[
     {
        product_image: img1.jpg
     },
     {
        product_image: img2.jpg
     }
  ],
  "array2":[
     {
        product_image: img3.jpg
     }
  ]
```

Comment: can you show us Postman input  for this request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join imagesArrays using flatmap and loop through image.

```
let allImages = fileParameters.values.flatMap{$0}

allImages.enumerated().forEach {    
   multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation($1.values.first), withName: "product_image\($0)", fileName: "\($0).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
}
```

Comment: Thanks man you made my day with just one line of code "withName: "product_image[\($0)]"
 
:)

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will work

make your key array type:-

```
 multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "product_image[\(index)]", fileName: "\(index).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
```

make your loops to create the index value in incremented order like 0,1,2,3.....N